upgrade to 24.04 LT locked up
The screen went blank during the 24.04 LTS upgrade.
I moved the mouse and saw flashing mouse pointer tracks. Not a solid pointer track.
I closed the lid and reopened it. I had a second to view the screen before it blanked.
Using my phone I captured an image of the screen when I did it again.
It was waiting for input on an upgrade to thunderbird question but the screen was locked and it wouldn't accept any input.
The upgrade box behind it showed it was unpacking xfce-appfinder (amd64) and it was stopped.
Subsequent trys were met with a blank screen.
I let it set again and tried it an hour later with the same results.
I'd believe the upgrade went bad.
Short of booting with a thumb drive and mounting the vlm2 volume and doing a copy from the boot disk what else can be done? I think in the past I shrank the vlm2 volume and reinstalled in the freespace and moved it to the vlm2 volume then deleted and removed the other one.
